# Hyperledger Blockchain Scalability for State DB and Chain (Transaction Log)

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

This is a scalability question for Hyperledger Fabric.

Understand that Hyperledger Fabric leverages couch DB to maintain current state.

Questions:

1. Is there HA (A/A and/or A/P) configuration for the state DB? How to avoid SPOF?
2. The chain is a transaction log. How big can this transaction log get? 100GB? without affecting speed of append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Fabric can utilize embedded LevelDB or external CouchDB to maintain state.  In either case, think of the state database as part of the peer - there is a 1:1 relationship between peer and its state database.  HA (A/A) in Fabric, and in blockchain in general, is provided at the node (peer) level.  Transactions can be endorsed by any peer(s) and are then ordered and delivered to all peers in the network. There is natural HA across the network, plus most organizations would typically host multiple peers for 'local' HA as well.  If a peer goes down you route traffic to your other peers.  If a peer or state database becomes corrupt you can rebuild it and it will state transfer blocks from other peers upon joining the channel.

2) The chain is an append-only transaction log on local disk or direct attached storage. It is not a single file but appends to a new file once the prior file reaches a threshold size (64MB by default). Therefore the maximum size of the transaction log is bound only by disk space.

Comment: thanks Dave! In what file format is this transaction log in? Was trying to locate in my disk but unable to. Also, based on my understand of what you said, the transaction log is multiple 64mb files in the disk? Is my understanding correct?